# Locking hints for table with concurrent read and write access

Tags: sql, transactions, locking, sql-server-2000

I've seen a few similar questions but none that quite address this scenario.

I have an online assessment application that presents users with questions, one question per page, and records their answers. Users can navigate between questions, and their responses are automatically saved.

When navigating from one page (question Q1) to another (question Q2), the database has to:

- UPDATE this user's response to Q1 (if it exists) or INSERT a response to Q1.
- SELECT this user's response to Q2 (if it exists) to populate the page.

The [RESPONSE] table is a point of contention with many users concurrently reading and writing. However, each user will only ever read and write to *their own rows*.

This leads me to think I could use (READUNCOMMITTED), <strike>and UPDATE with (NOLOCK)</strike> safely. My worry is, I don't want to have the situation where a user goes forward a page, and then jumps back and gets the old data before it has been updated. I can put the two operations inside a transaction, but if I'm using NOLOCK hints will that make any difference?

What locking strategy can I use to alleviate contention on this table?

We're currently on SQL2000.

Comment: Is security for the site set up that you prevent concurrent logins for the same user?  If not you might have an issue with the locking hints...

Comment: What do you mean "UPDATE with (NOLOCK)"? Update will always take locks. `NOLOCK` only applies to `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @JNK: Yes, the same user ID will only be logged in once.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the heads up. I've always let SQL server do its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to use the `rowlock` hint and make sure that you have appropriate indexes such that the rows can be seeked to directly without needing to scan other rows belonging to different users.

Comment: So just to be clear, no need for SELECT with NOLOCK, because only the rows being written will be locked. Row locks on other users' rows will not affect my select as long as there is an appropriate index (on userID) in place.

Comment: @GC - Yes. As long as they are taking row locks on different sets of rows there shouldn't be a problem (there might be a slight contention on page latches from concurrent updates but probably not worth worrying about up front) By the Way you can use SQL Profiler to trace the locks that are taken by your queries.